# Number 1 is randomly appended to the end of my JWT secret after URL encoding

Tags: c#, jwt, sha256

I have searched every nook and cranny for a solution to my problem but I cannot seem to find one.

I have a class that utilizes methods to create a JSON Web Token. The web token I create needs match the following (notice there is not a number 1 on the far right of my secret):

```
eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJhcHBrZXkiOiIxMjMtNDU2LTc4OS0wIiwicmVzb3VyY2UiOiJnZXRfZ2VvY29kZSJ9.xGLb92d6yVLqLf5TnrahMCxm-OGTHmXiXLvnRUqLWYM
```

The token I generate matches the token above, except for the fact that a number 1 is randomly appended on the far right end of my token:

```
eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJhcHBrZXkiOiIxMjMtNDU2LTc4OS0wIiwicmVzb3VyY2UiOiJnZXRfZ2VvY29kZSJ9.xGLb92d6yVLqLf5TnrahMCxm-OGTHmXiXLvnRUqLWYM1
```

As you can see, that is the section of the JWT that holds the secret. Let me demonstrate how I am generating and encrypting the token so you can help with diagnosing the issue. I will show you the entire class then walk you through the methods.

Here is the entire class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

namespace Project.JWT
{
    public class Token
    {

        public string CreateToken(string resource, string appkey, string secret, string algorithm)
        {
            if (algorithm != "HS256")
                return "Algorithm not supported";

            JwtPayload payload = new JwtPayload
            {
                appkey = appkey,
                resource = resource
            };

            return EncodeToken(payload, secret);

        }

        public static string EncodeToken(JwtPayload jwtPayload, string secret)
        {
            const string algorithm = "HS256";

            var header = new Header
            {
                typ = "JWT",
                alg = algorithm
            };

            var jwt = Base64Encode(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(header)) + "." + Base64Encode(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jwtPayload));

            jwt += "." + Sign(jwt, secret);

            return jwt;
        }


        public static string Base64Encode(dynamic obj)
        {
            Type strType = obj.GetType();

            var base64EncodedValue = Convert.ToBase64String(strType.Name.ToLower() == "string" ? Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(obj) : obj);
            return base64EncodedValue;
        }


        private static string Sign(string str, string key)
        {


            byte[] signature;

            using (var crypto = new HMACSHA256(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key)))
            {
                signature = crypto.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str));
            }

            return System.Web.HttpServerUtility.UrlTokenEncode(signature);

        }

    }


    public class Header
    {
        public string alg { get; set; }
        public string typ { get; set; }
    }

    public class JwtPayload
    {
        public string appkey { get; set; }
        public string resource { get; set; }
    }


}
```

First, The CreateToken method is passed the credentials to create the payload. It then calls the EncodeToken method that takes the payload and secret as a parameter. Keep in mind that my secret is a hard-coded string that never changes throughout the lifetime of the app; So I know that is not randomly generating the number 1.

Line 39, The header and payload are converted into a base 64 string and joined together by a dot which generates the first two parts of my token perfectly:

```
eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJhcHBrZXkiOiIxMjMtNDU2LTc4OS0wIiwicmVzb3VyY2UiOiJnZXRfZ2VvY29kZSJ9
```

Then, I call the Sign method on line 41 which request the signing of my token using the SHA256 algorithm.

The Sign method accepts the combined header and payload as str then the secret is passed through as key.

On line 62, I begin the creation of the signature using my custom key, which is "testsecret".

Then I URL encode the signature on line 67, just before returning it. When I return it, line 41 combines the three parts of the token together, thus leaving me with a perfect JWT...... except for the number "1" at the far right end of the secret.

please help.

Answer (score 2):

It's to do with the way that [HttpServerUtility.UrlTokenEncode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.urltokenencode(v=vs.110).aspx) works, emphasis mine:

> Encodes a byte array into its equivalent string representation using base 64 digits, **which is usable for transmission on the URL**

You'll know that depending on its length a Base64 string will be padded with `=` appended to the end.  The `=` is not considered URL safe and so is replaced with an integer denoting the count, in this case `1`.

You can test this by debugging and replace the line below...

```
return System.Web.HttpServerUtility.UrlTokenEncode(signature);
```

...with this...

```
return Convert.ToBase64String(signature);
```

...and inspecting the return value.

You'll see that it ends with a `=` so `HttpServerUtility.UrlTokenEncode` replaces it with a `1`.